# DataGridViewPaintParts enumeration backgrounds

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

With regard to the DataGridViewPaintParts enumeration, there are three kinds of background within it:

Background, ContentBackground and SelectionBackground.

What does the ContentBackground draw? I can turn this on and off by using e.PainParts within the DataGridView RowPrePaint event, but it doesn't appear to do anything.

MSDN is less than helpful in it's description.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that when using TextBox cells as I am, nothing is actually painted with ContentBackground.

If a Button is used as a cell (for example), then the button would be drawn by this option.